# mutually exclusive attributes to one resource in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I need some help here, I'm trying to write a module for azure ACI container instance.
I found two attributes are mutually exclusive, dns_name_label and network_profile_id.
If I set ip_address_type to public, I would like to use dns_name_label, but network_profile_id can't come to the same script
vice versa, If I set ip_address_type to Private, I have to define network_profile_id, but dns_name_label can't come to script

If there anyway to contain both dns_name_label and network_profile_id, judging on ip_address_type?

```
resource "azurerm_container_group" "this" {
  name                = var.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  ip_address_type     = var.ip_address_type
  dns_name_label = var.ip_address_type =="Public"&&length(var.dns_name_label)> 0 ? var.dns_name_label :""
   os_type            = var.os_type
  restart_policy     = var.restart_policy
  network_profile_id = var.ip_address_type == "Private" ? azurerm_network_profile.this[0].id : ""

}
```

note above code doesn't work, I get error

```
"network_profile_id": conflicts with dns_name_label
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [null](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/types.html#null) instead of `""`, which will eliminate the attribute from the resource is `null` is set as its value:

```
resource "azurerm_container_group" "this" {
  name                = var.name
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  ip_address_type     = var.ip_address_type
  dns_name_label = var.ip_address_type =="Public"&&length(var.dns_name_label)> 0 ? var.dns_name_label : null
   os_type            = var.os_type
  restart_policy     = var.restart_policy
  network_profile_id = var.ip_address_type == "Private" ? azurerm_network_profile.this[0].id : null
}
```

Comment: thanks! that works! I thought "" has the same effect as null, apparently not lol

Comment: @RogerChen No problem. Glad it worked out:-)